# catch not running javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I have an async await function that handles form submission in React Native:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const credentials = { email, password }
    try {
      login(credentials)
    } catch {
      console.error('ERROR')
      //external function to reset form
      resetForm()
      return
    }

    // User authenticated, go to home screen   
    await goToHomeScreen()
  }
```

Where login(), which makes the API call, is

```
const login = (credentials) => {
  axios
    .post(`${MY_API}/login`, credentials)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data) 
    })
    .catch(() => {
      throw 'Error'
    })
}
```

The idea is that if the authentication call fails, my login() throws an error, which should run the `return` in my handleSubmit's catch {}, ending the function. However, the catch never runs, and goToHomeScreen() runs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `return axios.post...` this should enable you to throw error up top

Comment: Adding return axios to login() didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

not just return but do something

```
axios
.get(url)
.then((response) => {
  console.log('response', response);
}
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('CATCH');
  window.alert('CATCH');
}
```

Comment: I have other actions in my catch, added for clarification

Comment: i updated my answer, my CATCH is working correctly here with an invalid URL the error would be a 400 Network Unavailable

Comment: Worked fine for me, check here https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-allen-cmw8w

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working for me

```
const login = (credentials) => {
   axios
   .post(`${MY_API}/login`, credentials)
   .then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data) 
   })
  .catch((error ) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: `.catch(error => Promise.reject(error))` is redundant; the result is identical to not having that catch at all.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using async-await, you can call login as:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const credentials = { email, password }
    try {
      await login(credentials)
    } catch {
      console.error('ERROR')
      //external function to reset form
      resetForm()
      return
    }

    // User authenticated, go to home screen   
    await goToHomeScreen()
  }

const login = async (credentials) => {
  return await axios.post(`${MY_API}/login`, credentials);
}
```

it will solve the issue